# How do I check for open transactions on a psycopg2 connection?

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2, python-db-api

How can I check for open transactions on a [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) connection? I intend to add it to my unit/functional tests since Python's DB API uses implicit transactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the connection's [`status`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.status) attribute:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import STATUS_BEGIN, STATUS_READY

if conn.status == STATUS_READY:
    print("No transaction in progress.")
elif conn.status == STATUS_BEGIN:
    print("A transaction is in progress.")
```

Alternatively, the [transaction status](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#transaction-status-constants) can be obtained with [`connection.get_transaction_status()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.get_transaction_status).

To manually check for in-progress transaction you could use PostgreSQL's [statistics collector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/monitoring-stats.html):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle in transaction';
```

Comment: Should also check STATUS_PREPARED. (meaning transaction is in progress)